# GetElementsByTagName Returning [object HTMLParagraphElement]

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, automation

I have the below code, wherein I'm trying to open a series of urls and pull in the data from each url (example: http://apps.mohltc.ca/ltchomes/detail.php?id=2588&lang=en). Of most interest to me would be those labeled as "Local Health Integration Network", "Licensee" and "Licensed Beds".

As it stands, I'm trying to just pull in all elements with tag name "p" and deal with the data scrubbing later on. My code currently pulls in "[object HTML Paragraph Element]" instead of the array that I'm hoping for. Can someone explain why this is?

```
Sub ImportLicenseeData()

Dim ie As Object
Dim LH As Object
Dim r As Integer

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

For r = 4 To 10
    With ie
        ie.Visible = False
        ie.Navigate Cells(r, "H").Value
        Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> 4): DoEvents: Loop

    Set Doc = ie.Document

    Set LH = Doc.getElementsByTagName("p")

    End With

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & r).Value = LH

Next r

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Set LH = Doc.getElementsByTagName("p")` retrieves a `DispHTMLElementCollection` object but not an array. You should create the array looping through collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim LH As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim htmlEle1 as IHTMLElement
```

It requires Microsoft HTML Object Library reference. Then you can interact with elements of LH collection (it's not an array) like this:

```
Set LH = Doc.getElementsByTagName("p")

For Each htmlEle1 in LH
   Debug.Print htmlEle1.innerText
Next htmlEle1
```

Comment: When I edit to reflect the above I'm getting a type mismatch error for

    Set LH = Doc.getElementsByTagName("p")

How would I go about debugging this?

Comment: @JPJP `Dim LH As IHTMLElementCollection`

Comment: @omegastripes that's true `HTMLObjectElement` would work as an ancestor of another collection of objects, not a collection itself. I've changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone. I wasn't too familiar with handling the HTML Elements, so I ended up going with a different approach. Appreciate the feedback regardless.

via http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=178150

```
Sub RetrieveHTML()

Dim rngSelect As Range
Dim sURL As String

Set rngSelect = Range("H8", Range("H8").End(xlDown))
Debug.Print rngSelect.Address

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

For Each c In rngSelect
    sURL = c.Value
    With ie
        .Visible = False
        .Navigate sURL
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
            Range(c.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value = ie.Document.DocumentElement.outerHTML
        End With
    Next c

End Sub
```